# Docker share volume with REMOTE machine

Tags: docker

Using docker, its quite easy to share volumes between the container and the host machine, using the `-v <local_path>:<container_path>` option.

I was wondering, in a setup of a container on a *remote* machine, can I bind volumes in the same manner?

Example:
I have a remote machine on AWS.
I want to launch a container on that remote machine, and bind a volume from that remote machine, into my local PC.

Is this natively possible in docker?

Comment: I don't think this is possible unless you have the remote volume mapped to the host and then the host path network shared with your machine.

Comment: Or maybe using a volume driver that has network support? : https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7249

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: NO

you can however use nfs or something similar to mount the folder onto a remote storage